# Algorithm: Computing the intersection of two conics

Tags: reference-request, conic-sections

I am looking for a detailed description of an algorithm for the classical problem of computing the intersection of two conics curves. The curves are given by two equations of the form:

$a x^2 + b y^2 + c xy + d x + e y + f = 0$

I need the algorithm to extend my graphics library MetaPict.
If possible I prefer references with pseudo-code (or real code),
but other references are also welcome.

Comment: The algorithm for computing the intersection of two conics are easily found in many places. [Here's a Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Intersecting_two_conics). For help converting this to code or pseudo-code, please ask on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: It is indeed easy to find a description of the pencil method. It is however not easy to find a description where numerical stability is considered.

Comment: For numerical stability, the website scicomp.stackexchange may be a better place.

Comment: The book "Perspectives on Projective Geometry" by Jürgen Richter-Gebert was what I was after. Details here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767225/algorithm-intersection-of-two-conics